# SQL *= statement (outer join)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, vb6, sybase

currently, i am converting VB6 to VB.NET.
After conversion, i want to insert / select in SQL
but i need to know what is the meaning of my sql statement.

My Statement:

```
XXX  where  adj.reasonid *=  re.reasonid and (status <> 'A'OR action = 'H')
```

Can someone know *= mean? and

`in (status <> 'A'OR action = 'H')` is that mean either one condition can select the data?

Comment: For 2nd: yes it will return data if `status` is not A or `action` is H. This condition works as follows, (1 - true, 0 - false) `1 or 1 = 1 | 1 or 0 = 1 | 0 or 1 = 1| 0 or 0 = 0 `

Answer (score 2):

`*=` is alternate (obsolete I believe) syntax for left outer join.

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to up-vote useful answers, and accept whichever you considered to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's old syntax for `Outer Join` in sql server.

SQL Server has long supported two forms of `OUTER JOIN syntax`, 
the `ANSI syntax (using LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, etc.), 
and the simplified `T-SQL syntax (using`*= and =*`).`

http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/1/15/SQL-Server-2005-Outer-Join-Gotcha

In your code.

```
where  adj.reasonid Left Outer Join re.reasonid 
and (status <> 'A' OR action = 'H')
```

For in.

```
in (status <> 'A'OR action = 'H')
```

OR Operator only evaluates expressions until it find a TRUE result.